# Groovy paradigm for conditional with find

Tags: groovy

This code works, but the duplicate find seems less than optimal. Is it possible to implement the same functionality without the duplication?

```
def pattern = ~'some_regex'
def inFile = new File('in')

inFile.eachLine { String line ->
    if (line.find(pattern)) {
        line.find(pattern) { match ->
            ... // do something
        }   
    } 
    else {
        ... // do something (else)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `eachMatch()`

```
inFile.eachLine { String line ->
    String matched
    line.eachMatch( pattern ){ 
      matched = it[ 0 ]
      doSomethingWithMatch matched
    }
    if( !matched ) doNoMatch()
}
```

Comment: And if no match occurs, how would I execute an alternative block instead?